# UTF-7 XSS attacks in modern browsers

Tags: web-browser, javascript, xss, encoding

I've recently read [Ned Batchelders article on UTF-7 XSS-attacks](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200704/xss_with_utf7.html). I tested [his examples](http://nedbatchelder.com/utf7.html), but could not get any UTF-7 attack to work in modern browsers. I tried recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari so far.

I know that Chrome has some XSS-attack prevention mechanisms but to my experience, Firefox has a more "generous" mechanism of executing javascript, even when it's broken - however, none of these browsers seems to select the UTF-7 charset by default if the site is using (but not explicitly declaring) it.

So: Does anybody know why this is not working anymore? It seems that the UTF-7 detection mechanism has changed, maybe even for security reasons? Can UTF-7 attacks still target modern browsers if there is no way to change charset declaration within the document or manipulate the headers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This exploit is only possible in old versions of Internet Explorer. Modern browsers will not auto detect the encoding as UTF-7.

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#UTF-7_encoding):-

> This does not work in any modern browser without changing the encoding type which is why it is marked as completely unsupported.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7#Security):-

> To mitigate this problem systems should perform decoding before validation and should avoid attempting to autodetect UTF-7.
>   Older versions of Internet Explorer can be tricked into interpreting the page as UTF-7.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there is more information on this topic but maybe that is all there is to say.

Comment: IE will render UTF-7 pages if it is stated in the `content-type`,  the only change is that IE's content sniffing no longer attempts UTF-7 encoding.

Answer (score 6):

[Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=233355) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=414064) seem to no longer support UTF-7 in any format.  The [HTML5 specification says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#character-encodings):

> User agents must support the encodings defined in the WHATWG Encoding standard. User agents should not support other encodings.
>
> User agents must not support the CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1 and SCSU encodings. [[CESU8]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#refsCESU8) [[UTF7]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#refsUTF7) [[BOCU1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#refsBOCU1) [[SCSU]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#refsSCSU)
>
> Support for encodings based on EBCDIC is especially discouraged. This encoding is rarely used for publicly-facing Web content. Support for UTF-32 is also especially discouraged. This encoding is rarely used, and frequently implemented incorrectly.