# Why does OWASP ASVS require HTTP responses to have a content header specifying a character set?

Tags: web-application, appsec, owasp, asvs

The OWASP Application Security Verification Standard (**ASVS**), Version 3, states in clause V11.2:

> Verify that every HTTP response contains a content type header specifying a safe character set (e.g., `UTF-8`, `ISO 8859-1`).

What would be the threat of neglecting this requirement, and how could this be exploited?

Comment: [UFT-7 XSS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47489/utf-7-xss-attacks-in-modern-browsers) is one thing I can think of.

Comment: UTF-7 XSS is a specific type of attack. This is one aspect of the vulnerability. Beware that the browser's decision, based on Content-Type HTTP headers and HTML meta tags, on how to interpret the characters can be vague. If the browser accepts a meta tag over the value of the header, just setting the encoding scheme doesn't fully solve encoding vulnerabilities; how the webapp ( the prog lang & s/w libraries) handle characters are where the true problem lies. Think: percent encoding, double encoding & NULL Byte Encoding.

Answer (score 6):

Decrease client-side attacks.

For example : 
If the page that the XSS resides on doesn't provide a page charset header, or any browser that is set to UTF-7 encoding can be exploited with the following.
for example (UTF-7 encoding):

```
+ADw-SCRIPT+AD4-alert('XSS');+ADw-/SCRIPT+AD4-
```

And It Is hard to Prevent XSS Attacks

more info : [XSS with utf-7](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200704/xss_with_utf7.html)

Answer (score 1):

The 2008 paper from Blake Franz of Leviathan Security -- http://www.leviathansecurity.com/white-papers/flirting-with-mime-types -- identifies some of the original problem spaces with character sets.

Some tools correctly identify and explain this problem, such as Burp Suite Professional -- https://portswigger.net/KnowledgeBase/Issues/Details/00800200_HTMLdoesnotspecifycharset

You will see mention of character sets in the OWASP Testing Guides on Stored XSS:

> This design flaw can be exploited in browser MIME mishandling attacks.
>   For instance, innocuous-looking files like JPG and GIF can contain an
>   XSS payload that is executed when they are loaded by the browser. This
>   is possible when the MIME type for an image such as image/gif can
>   instead be set to text/html. In this case the file will be treated by
>   the client browser as HTML.
>
> Also consider that Internet Explorer does not handle MIME types in the
>   same way as Mozilla Firefox or other browsers do. For instance,
>   Internet Explorer handles TXT files with HTML content as HTML content.
>   For further information about MIME handling, refer to the whitepapers
>   section at the bottom of this chapter.

Further information can be found on the Wikipedia page under Charset Sniffing -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing